# Am I right in my conclusions about these series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm trying to decide if these series converge or diverge:

1. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(\frac{2n + 100 }{3n + 1 }\right)^n $$ Here $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{2n + 100 }{3n + 1 }\right)^n \ne 0$, so can we conclude that the series diverges?
2. $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left( n \sin \frac{1}{n} \right) $$ Can we compare this series with the divergent series $ \sum \log \sin(1/n)$ to conclude that it is divergent too?

Am I reaching the correct conclusion in each case?

Comment: For the first one use the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test).

Comment: For the second one, it's useful to know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin (x)}{x} = 1$ (essentially the unnormalized sinc function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function)

Answer (score 6):

1. We have
   $$\sqrt[n]{\left|(-1)^n \left(\frac{2n + 100 }{3n + 1 }\right)^n\right|}=\left(\frac{2n + 100 }{3n + 1 }\right)\to\frac{2}{3}<1$$
   so by the ratio test the series is convergent.
2. By the Taylor series we have
   $$\sin\left(\frac 1 n\right)=\frac 1 n +O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
   so
   $$\log\left(n\sin\left(\frac1 n\right)\right)=\log\left( 1  +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
   hence the series is convergent by limit comparison to the Riemann convergent series.

Comment: What is the "Riemann convergent series" ?

Comment: The series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

For the first series, use to **[root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)** to prove the series **converges**.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[\large n]{\left|(-1)^n \left(\frac{2n + 100}{3n + 1}\right)^n\right|}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2n + 100 }{3n + 1 }\right) = \frac23 < 1$$

Hence, $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{2n + 100}{3n + 1}\right)^n\;\;\text{converges}$$

---

For the second series, use the **comparison text** to prove the series **converges**, too.

**Clarification:**

We know by the Taylor series expansion that
$$\sin\left(\frac 1 n\right)=\frac 1 n +O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right).$$

It follows, then, that $$\log\left(n\sin\left(\frac1 n\right)\right)=\log\left(n \left(\frac 1n + O\left(\frac 1{n^3}\right)\right)\right) = 1 + O \left(\frac 1{n^2}\right) = O\left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)$$
So the series is convergent by comparison to $\sum \dfrac 1{n^2}$

Comment: No, you aren't. Since $ 0 < 1/n < \pi / 2$ for all $n$, the sine will remain positive.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to set up the comparison for the second series?

Comment: Indeed, I hardly imagine anybody asking this who would be able to solve the second question, based on such an indication.

Comment: @Saaqib I hope the added clarification helps! ;-)

Comment: OP: Was this addition to your post basically picked (with cosmetic modifications) from the other answer?