# Test of Convergent $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left| \log{\left( n \sin{\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right|$

Tags: calculus

I have doing the ratio test but fail, can anyne give me a hints to test the convergence of

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left| \log{\left( n \sin{\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right|$$

Comment: Related: [$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\log\left(n\sin\dfrac1n\right)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/470393/201168).

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x \to 0$ $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1-\frac{x^{2}}{6}+o(x^{2})$$
and $$\log(1+x)=x+o(x)$$
So $$\log\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=-\frac{x^{2}}{6}+o(x^{2})$$
Putting $x=\frac{1}{n}$, we see that the sequence is summable (it's bounded above by $M/n^{2}$ for some $M$)